# Versions of defaultDeep and defaults that override undefined and null values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for versions of Lodash's [`defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#defaults) and [`defaultsDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#defaultsDeep) that override `null` values in addition to `undefined`. I've looked at the source for `defaultsDeep` but couldn't figure out a simple way to get it working. I'd rather use a simple solution, possibly based on Lodash, than roll my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by using [`lodash#mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) to merge objects with [`lodash#isNil`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isNil) as the identifying condition to determine if a variable is `null` or `undefined`.

```
// Note: if you change `_.isNil` to `_.isUndefined`
// then you'd get the `_.defaults()` normal behavior
const nilMerge = (a, b) => _.isNil(a)? b: a;

const nilMergeDeep = (a, b) => (_.isObject(a) && !_.isArray(a))
  // recursively merge objects with nilMergeDeep customizer
  ? _.mergeWith({}, a, b, nilMergeDeep) 
  // let's use our default customizer
  : nilMerge(a, b);

// defaults not deep with null/undefined
const result1 = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, o3, nilMerge);

// defaults deep with null/undefined
const result2 = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, o3, nilMergeDeep);
```

```js
const o1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: null,
  x: {
    x1: 1,
    x2: 2,
    x3: null
  },
  z: null
};

const o2 = {
  a: 9999,
  d: 4,
  e: null,
  f: 123,
  x: {
    x3: 3,
    x4: null
  },
  z: ['a', 'b']
};

const o3 = {
  b: 9999,
  e: 5,
  f: 2,
  g: 234,
  x: {
    x4: 4,
    x5: 5,
    x6: ['hi', 'there']
  },
  z: ['c']
};

// Note: if you change `_.isNil` to `_.isUndefined`
// then you'd get the `_.defaults()` normal behavior
const nilMerge = (a, b) => _.isNil(a)? b: a;

const nilMergeDeep = (a, b) => (_.isObject(a) && !_.isArray(a))
  // recursively merge objects with nilMergeDeep customizer
  ? _.mergeWith({}, a, b, nilMergeDeep) 
  // let's use our default customizer
  : nilMerge(a, b);

// defaults not deep with null/undefined
const result1 = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, o3, nilMerge);

// defaults deep with null/undefined
const result2 = _.mergeWith({}, o1, o2, o3, nilMergeDeep);

console.log('defaults not deep with null/undefined');
console.log(result1);

console.log('defaults deep with null/undefined');
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/#mergeWith).

Ref: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2499

Comment: That's hardly a complete answer. Care to elaborate? I'm aware of `mergeWith` but it's non-trivial to implement what I'm asking with it.